# Convert byte array to playable mp4 file

Tags: java, android, arrays, voice

I need to do some processing on the raw file bytes and the algorithm is fine with working on .wav file but the problem is the .mp4 files it is not playable at all.
I think the problem that the file contains raw bytes only and no header

please help me

```
public void convert(String maskFlag, File endFile) 
{
    byte[] rawData = getarr(originalFile);
    byte[] effectedData = rawData.clone();

    effectedData = changePitch(rawData, parameters.getPitch());
    effectedData = changeVolume(effectedData, parameters.getVolume());
    effectedData = changeSpeed(effectedData, parameters.getSpeed());

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(endFile);
    out.write(effectedData);
    out.close();
}

byte[] getarr(File file) throws Exception 
{
   InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
   fis = new FileInputStream(file);
   byte [] byteArr = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
   return byteArr;
}
```

Comment: Mp4 files don't contain audio samples.  An mp4 file is a _container_ that could contain audio or video data that are encoded using any of a number of different _codecs_.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14 . You'll need a decoder in order to convert the data to audio samples.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_codecs

Comment: will any other format work, such as converting the data into a wav file?

Comment: thanks Mr james but how to do it in java I just dont know where to start?

Comment: I think no Mr Neji Im using media recoder and it don't have .wav output format